# Jython Remote debugging Intellij Idea, using Pycharm plugin

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, jython, pycharm, jython-2.5

Before marking this as a duplicate please read the full thread

```
OS                 - Windows XP
Primary Language   - Java
Scripting Language - Jython
IDE                - Intellij Idea
Python Plugin      - Pycharm
```

---

I am trying to remote debug my application which runs in Java and uses Jython as a scripting language. I followed the steps mentioned in the below link 
http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-python-remote-debug.html#commentsSection

- I can start the debugger
- When my application starts up, it is able to connect to the debugger

However I am getting below critical WARNING -

---

pydev debugger: CRITICAL WARNING: This version of python seems to be incorrectly compiled (internal generated filenames are not absolute)
pydev debugger: The debugger may still function, but it will work slower and may miss breakpoints
pydev debugger: Related bug: http://bugs.python.org/issue1666807

---

### The problem

Debugger doesn't stop at the break points.

I have searched lot of forums for the possible solutions -

- delete all *.pyc files
- reinstall python version
- extract python lib folder to local file and add to sys.path

None of these work for me.

Comment: Have you set up path mappings? Try to set suspend=True in settrace call and see debugger correctly stops and shows the source in PyCharm.

Comment: yup suspend=True makes the debugger stop on the next line in my source code. However after that it doesn't stop at any other breakpoint. Also just to clarify further, I am not using Pycharm as an IDE, instead I use it as a Intellij Plugin

Comment: You can try PyDev+Eclipse, it just works.

Comment: The warning `pydev debugger: CRITICAL WARNING: This version of python seems to be incorrectly compiled ` happens also with PyDev, it isn't harmful.